# Used the maximum 40 votes in a day, and more, but I'm not stopped from voting yet

Tags: discussion, voting, badges, deleted-answers, deleted-questions

So I used the maximum 40 votes for a day, and I happened to earn the `Vox Populi` badge for that.

However I've been voting for various questions and answers, and it's been 43 at the moment, but SO won't stop me from voting. Is this a bug or what's going on?

> [image]

Comment: All those numbers you blanked out are public ;)

Comment: Have some of the posts you voted on been deleted?

Comment: @OGHaza I am well aware of that being public, nothing secretive about it, but still there's no point of displaying it when my target is something else here. (:

Comment: @OGHaza Also it doesn't look very beautiful.

Comment: @nicael, on the contrary, he scored top points for use of drop shadow

Comment: -1 because the red square is not a circle, +1 because it has a drop shadow, -1 because it isn't freehand, +1 because it's red, and +1 because this is a good question. Total: +1 (If you're confused, read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/238586)).

Comment: @Neeku "my target is something else": A *Good question* silver badge on meta?

Comment: OMG! I just can't see how these comments are going off-topic.
@ClickRick Nope. I don't care a silver badge on meta; and I don't think graying those numbers out, would help me get one! The point of that screenshot is to show the vote cast of the day, so nothing wrong with graying out everything else. (:

Comment: @OGHaza The subject pronoun for females is "she" in English, not "he". (:

Comment: @Neeku my apologies. On the subject of assuming OP is male I once said ["I bet I'm yet to refer to a girl as a he"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222024/does-the-so-community-view-itself-as-gender-neutral#comment721549_222024) - I can no longer make such a claim :(

Comment: @OGHaza Haha! No worries. It made my day! You can use *s/he* instead of *they* although they're both the same in terms of length. Cool link. Will keep myself amused reading the rest of it during the weekend!

Comment: @Neeku comments going off-topic? Impossible. Meta is where off-topic is the on-topic.

Comment: @OGHaza You wouldn't have 83 up-votes for any comments at any near future if I hadn't have uploaded that screenshot. :P Glad I helped the stats. :D :P

Answer (score 91, accepted):

It's because some of the questions/answers you've voted on have been deleted, thus giving you back your vote(s) to cast again.

Votes on deleted posts do not count toward your daily allotment.

[[source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124818/262755)]

Comment: Thanks unit. That was actually the case, and turns out there were exactly 3 deleted posts. Trying to vote for one more question, I was stopped!