# Are all recent reputation changes visible in a user's reputation tab?

Tags: discussion, reputation, profile-page

- Are all recent reputation changes visible in a user's profile?
- Are there any exceptional cases where reputation changes are visible only to the users and not others?
- Are reputation changes due to reversal of serial upvoting visible in the reputation tab of a user?
- Are the above information visible to all or only to the owner of the profile?
- If the users who downvoted a user are deleted, will there be visible reputation changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are all recent reputation changes visible in an user's profile?

Yes. If you don't see some of them, check the "show removed posts" checkbox at the bottom of the page.

> Are there any exceptional cases where reputation changes are visible only to the users and not others?

Yes. If you downvote an answer, then only you will see that in your reputation tab. The same if a post, that gave you rep, is deleted; it is only visible to you.

> Are reputation changes due to reversal of serial upvoting visible in the reputation tab?

Yes, they are, and they are visible to everyone.

> Are there any exceptional cases where rep changes are not shown on OP's profile?

No, all rep changes are shown to the owner. If you don't see some of them, check the "show removed posts" checkbox at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

The down-votes are still there. I started a different browser where I've never logged into Stack Overflow, and searched for my user profile. Expanding the dates from the reputation tab, you must definitely be able to see the down-votes, since they exist, and aren't removed.

[image]

And then from the page for each question, clicking on the score would show the history, although you need to be logged in as a Stack Overflow user to be able to see it.

[image]

P.S. Not sure if this is actually an answer, but this would be too long for a comment apart from the pictures.

Comment: Did you mean the two downvotes on Jun 25? and one after the question? My mistake, As your original question was on June 29, I thought you got downvotes recently. Thanks for a great answer +1

Comment: I updated my question after I got the third down-vote on July 1st. As you see the questions are over a year old at this time, and not too popular that I'd get random votes everyday, so it does mean that someone just walks and down-votes a bit, and leaves! :-/