# Is it useful to report off-site abuse to Stack Overflow if it originated at Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, abuse

I have a blog which is infrequently maintained, and when I signed in today, I discovered two extremely abusive comments directed at me. These were based apparently on some editing I did on someone's question, probably a week or two ago.

I appreciate this is not Stack Overflow's problem, and I am not bothered about it, so I have moved them to trash and am happy to move on. However, I wonder if reporting this information to Stack Overflow may be useful for moderators to inform their future moderation decisions in relation to specific users?

A real-looking email address was supplied, even though WordPress does not require it, so it is possible that the user wished to be associated with their comments. It is therefore possible that this email would match an address in Stack Overflow's user database. I've had a cursory check as to what edit might have triggered it, but the search tools aren't very suitable for this sort of search. I imagine the IP address would probably identify the user also, or at least narrow it down a great deal.

I believe I have seen it suggested that abuse off-site that originates from a dispute on Stack Overflow is still interesting to Stack Overflow, in case an account suspension in response may help change the poster's general attitude. (This may be a duplicate of another Meta post, but I could not find one just now).

Comment: Aha, thanks @vaultah - thought I'd seen something before! My search-fu failed me this time.

Comment: Shog's reponse on the other thread can probably be regarded as an official response: if the abuse is serious, send it to `team@stackoverflow.com` and they'll see what they can do.

Comment: Also [this is related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261941/what-do-i-do-about-receiving-an-offensive-email-from-another-user-on-stack-overf), and gives similar advice.

Comment: Comments calling me "Hilter (sic) Merkel" were reposted in an off-site Bitcoin forum. That was a surprise :P

Comment: Heh @ModusTollens - there is often a correlation between abusive folks and base illiteracy. Mine regarded me, amongst all manner of unpleasant and homophobic nonsense, as a "looser". Ha!