# User sends harassment email outside of network due to disagreement with question closure

Tags: support, harassment

Is there any recourse to a user harassing me outside of the network, because he/she disagrees with me closing the question? I was called out for cyberbullying when all I did was leave a comment pointing out issues with the code and about async/await.

[image: screenshot of the harassment email]

The OP has consistently reverted edits from several others, including a moderator.

The OP also keeps reverting the edits meant to keep the question succinct and free of extraneous comments. The text that we have removed was as follows, which I felt wasn’t necessary:

> Note: I am not looking for links as a response. No one is obligated to read or respond, but if you do, please respect that.
> If someone wants to be helpful and has the time to look through my specific code and offer insights, then I'd appreciate that person's response, but no links as responses, please. And please do not feel obligated to comment or reply unless you have the time to actually read my code and want to do so (and have the needed knowledge and skill). Thank you for understanding!

Comment: This may be better posted as a flag to moderators rather than on meta. They are best equipped to deal with this privately with the offending party.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have now submitted a flag as you have mentioned :)

Comment: Report that user to the mentioned website, together with a link to their profile here, their email and with the full name when available. When they wants to be a bully, then they can be reported as such.

Comment: The mail is absolutely unacceptable. But please, if you're ever again in the situation that a user rolls back things like that, flag for moderator attention. If you have to revert a rollback a second time, it's almost always better that a moderator helps (sends message to user or locks the post).

Comment: @BDL also worth noting that two rollbacks from the same user will automatically trigger a mod flag

Comment: Also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380075/

Comment: Looks like a mod has noticed this meta post and locked the problematic post. Also, looks like the user doesn't understand how Stack Overflow works, you can move on from this issue. However and unfortunately, I don't think there's anything that SO can do for harassment emails outside of the network.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your input. I just really want to make sure that closing a question does not constitute as cyber bullying. You don’t really know what you’d get into out here.

Comment: I also have to pedantically point out that should anyone ever say to you that "their" posts are "their" property, please refer them to reread what the [CC-by-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) licensing implies. "Theirs" is only the first revision of the post.

Comment: An additional note is that no, closure of a post certainly does not constitute cyber-bullying just as much as editing someone's post does not (by itself, of course, any mechanism can be abused). You used the official mechanisms provided by Stack Exchange. This is just the type that attempts to scare others by threat of legal action - I even recognize the email style (you can find a similar demeanor on YT when copyright holders try to scare content creators into submission).

Comment: @OlegValter Pretty empty threat too, cyberbullying.org just points to how to report people on individual platforms (not even including SO), and is America based... while Terry isn't

Comment: @Nick yeah, that's pretty much what these emails tend to amount to, after all - a toothless "I will report/reported you to <insert something scary-looking here>" that is *explicitly* designed to scare the recipient and bearing no legal credibility in reality.

Comment: There really wasn't any need to go to and fro with rollbacks. De-escalation using polite comments or early moderator involvement after two to three rollbacks should've calmed the whole situation down. In any case, a off site threat is unacceptable as your actions/edits were still in line with SO guidelines.

Comment: @TheMaster Just to clarify: the email was received after closing the question as duplicate, and the rollbacks happened the day after, when I tried to go back to the question to check if what I written crossed the line of harassment/bullying. That was when I realized OP reverted all edits to the question.

Comment: Lori was clearly wrong. And you were right. But I'm still of the opinion that you could've handled it much better. She clearly thought she owned the questions.  She thought you were stalking and harassing her at "revision 14" after your involvement in closing last two of her questions. I can't see deleted comments. So, I can't see  whether she was completely unreasonable. But in such cases, Don't you think it's better to cease and let someone else handle it - maybe the other members of the community or moderators, instead  of a direct conflict(which could be perceived as retaliation)?

Comment: @TheMaster I just felt that name calling wasn't justified, considering that she was the one who doxxed me and found my personal email (which will take considerable effort, but not impossible) and sent me that email. And yes, I could've stopped rolling back after awhile but I didn't know what was the right way to fix a user vandalizing his/her own posts all the time. Now I know that once more than two rollbacks were made, a flag will be raised: and I will simply let mods handle it. I have never stalked or harrassed her at any point: she started it herself, actually.

Comment: @TheMaster I've never experienced an "edit/rollback war" so far (a first for everyone I guess?), but now I know that the mods have tools to deal with it, so I know to leave it be next time :) However, Lori was the one who stalked and harassmed me first. And she even wrote additional follow up emails about how I make life hard for "women in tech". Which I find strange, since throughout our discussion we have never talked about OP's gender. I was only focused on making the question succinct and relevant. I am happy to provide additional transcripts of what she wrote me, if ever necessary.

Comment: Terry, I was only mentioning better way of handling in retrospect. I'm sure we will all learn to adapt better as our experience grows.

Comment: @TheMaster For sure, it's a learning lesson for me too :) thanks for the information!

Comment: Since this thread keeps going, another pedantic comment: I have to note that disgruntled folks falling back on accusations of being bigoted against <insert a tech minority here> is actually very harmful for the very valid cause when the claims are unsubstantiated (and I highly suspect they were in this case). Unfortunately, that is a very easy way of making a recipient look bad these days and another common psychological tactic. It is saddening to see but after empty threats of legal action it is only natural that the bigotry argument would be used.