# Please, no more "cvpls". Let's have "club" moderators instead

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, downvotes, voting

Users are allowed broad discretion in casting votes<sup>1</sup>... you'll often see mods say to "vote however you like".  I'd like to point out the *you* in that -- *YOU* are responsible for your own votes, and for reading and understanding posts before you vote on them.  Voting rings often go hand-in-hand with proxy voting, where users accept each others' assessment in lieu of their own analysis.  The very phrase "close vote please", abbreviates as *cvpls*, is a direct request for someone to take your word for it.  (Ditto for "downvote please" and "delete please").

This is clear abuse of the system; while it does allow closing questions faster, it also exacerbates the effect of human error.  If users were trusted enough to single-click to close questions, they'd be some sort of moderator.  Stack Exchange is designed so that community moderation scales up with content volume, not by making individual users more powerful (the net effect of proxy voting), but by having ever-increasing numbers of users who wield voting privileges.  That's why there's a daily cap on votes after all, to slow individual users down and have them take time to fully evaluate posts before voting.

The appropriate use of voting rings is to bring attention to questionable posts for more users to independently assess.  Not proxying.  Ever.  But they've clearly moved inappropriately in the proxying direction, on a very large scale.

Some specific objective problems with proxy voting:

- It appears that the post has been evaluated by multiple users who agree, when in fact as few as one made the decision and the others just piled on without actually doing a second evaluation.
- The delete vote rings [give votes back](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261686/103167) (but not close votes, thanks Raff) to themselves, allowing them to exceed the designed-in limits.

Perhaps posts aren't getting voting attention from five real independently-thinking users quickly enough to stop FGITW feeding of vampires.  But if something is worth doing, it is worth doing right.  Proxy voting is not doing it right, it is dishonest.

Instead, I propose creation of a "club moderator" role (like diamond mod, it's the name of a suit in a deck of cards).  This will be a mini diamond-moderator, which only one privilege, single-vote closure, and even that will be weakened.  Doing this will eliminate the abuse present in proxy-voting rings:

- Club moderators will be elected, not self-appointed.
- Closed questions will clearly indicate that a single user cast the vote.
- A close vote cast by a club moderator will not be locked like moderator closure and deletion.  It simply has the weight of up to five normal votes.  But it can be reversed by the community.
- Club moderator votes only work on the first closure.  If the community has already voted to reopen, club votes carry no extra weight.
- <strike>Proxy-voting will be stomped on with a vengeance after the first round of club moderator elections.</strike> We can wait and see whether close voting rings are left with nothing to do, when just outright closing the question becomes easier than sending it to the ring.
- Club voting only enables closing questions.  There is by design no replacement for proxy downvotes or organized deletion, which don't have public visibility, and revert back to "one user, one vote, always think before voting".

We can discuss whether club votes, like Mjolnir, should be limited to the user's tags.  And whether there should be a daily limit on club votes per user.

---

<sup>1</sup>And the user discretion only applies to up- and down-votes, anyway.

Comment: Can you link to some examples?  I've never seen this, and spend an unhealthy amount of time on this site.  Maybe it's more prevalent in a time zone I'm not in?  I also don't see how Stack Overflow would benefit from that club moderator role.  We already have plenty of moderator tools for non-moderators, in my opinion.

Comment: @Brad: See https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=site:chat.stackoverflow.com+cv-pls+-%22test+room%22 and there's even a [browser extension](https://cv-pls.pieterhordijk.com/) to make proxy voting easier :(

Comment: @BenVoigt We have our tag based 'mini clubs' and ***mighty mjölnir*** already?

Comment: Ha, the SO Close voters room is on top of my search result!. You're welcome!

Comment: Ah, these turn up in chat?  That at least explains why I've never seen them.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Mjolnir is limited to close-as-duplicate.  I'm talking about empowering users (by election) to immediately close using any/all reasons, subject to community reversal.

Comment: Just to make the problem clear: it all comes together here: http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/773/low-quality-posts-hq

Comment: @rene: Yeah, and the wording in there is explicitly a suggestion to "Don't bother looking at the post, just vote like I say" :(  If the close decision is being made by one person, the UI needs to indicate that.  And these chatbots and vote requests undermine that.

Comment: @BenVoigt Well, what else than a duplicate would make a reasonable close reason, within a tag based community over the standard close reasons (which can't be sorted out tag based at all)?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: That's why I didn't make linking to tags directly part of the idea.  Still, resource requests and debug-this-for-me-without-code and do-my-homework often have language tags.  And sometimes domain expertise helps sort out "there is no information" from "there's information which only a domain expert can understand".

Comment: @Downvoters: I'm curious what *exactly* you object to.  Because right now I'm assuming that it's the accountability associated with having **one name** attached to the close decision.  Or are you concerned you might not get support in an election?  Or is it users not currently involved in voting rings, and you want the voting rings to go away without replacement.  Please **leave an answer** and explain.

Comment: Ah the meta effect -- now @BenVoigt has made folks aware of these close vote chat rooms as many of us (myself included) were not aware of them previously. Will this have an opposite effect of that which he intended?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: You may note based on my suggested alternative that I don't disagree with the concept of one-vote closure by trusted users, which is the goal of these voting rings.  I just want it done in the light of day, with accountability.

Comment: Regarding down-voters (and I haven't voted yet on this issue), could it be that they simply don't agree with your premise, that your suggestion is better than the current functioning of this site?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: It's not that simple.  There should be something about the current system that I've failed to replicate that they want.  Or something I'm introducing that they don't want.  Whatever that "something" is, it should be identified in an answer.

Comment: as long as brainless "hotness algorithm" vomits into sidebar lists of [upvote-pls stuff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238514/165773 "Users arriving at a bad Hot Network Question should be able to express their dislike"), I fail to see compelling reason to worry about asking few active 3K+ readers to take a look at question that one of them (_personally_, not by braindead algorithm!) considered worthy of closure

Comment: @gnat: The voting rings don't ask "active readers to take a look".  They tell them how to vote.  If the fact that one of them personally considered it worthy of closure is enough to close it, the UI should say that.  Not say that five users agreed if they're proxy-voting.  Hence my idea.  If you want people simply to take a look, that's what the queues are for.

Comment: Why not just extend the mjölnir to all kinds of questions, not only duplicates?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Because some pretty anti-social users still manage to accrue gold tag badges.

Comment: Well, they don't have to be socialites, they just have to accurately judge question closures.  I don't see how limiting the capability to duplicates fixes that.

Comment: "that's what the queues are for" -- Ben, you got to be kidding. Close queue shows [less than 1/10 of questions voted to close](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278059/introducing-the-2014-end-of-the-year-close-vote-extravaganza "'There's about 165,000 questions with 1, 2, 3, or 4 close votes on them currently. There's about 11,000 questions that currently appear in the Close Votes queue...'"), there is no way it can substitute explicit request to take a look

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I'm fine with that (auto-awarding based on gold badges) if others are.  But I wanted to open discussion on having the power go beyond one's own tags as well.

Comment: All other things being equal, the simplest solution is usually the best one, and the mjölnir is already a proven system.

Comment: @BenVoigt am I correct that you don't participate in any chat rooms that use the cv-pls mechanism or am I just failing to find your chat account?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266994/is-bandwagon-voting-thru-chat-voting-fraud

Comment: @rene: I don't use that tag by choice, because I consider mob voting to be irresponsible.  Scratch that.  I consider telling the mob how to vote to be irresponsible.

Comment: @BenVoigt you already made clear that you find me irresponsible. I ask if you participate in a chatroom that uses that mechanism.

Comment: @rene: When I'm in chat, it's usually Lounge<C++>, which does bring posts to other users' attention, but (predominantly) does so organically without pasting a tag on to tell other users how to vote.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271899/remove-cv-pls-tag-from-chat-rooms

Comment: *The delete vote rings give close votes back to themselves*: is this really possible? The feature request [Refund close votes for questions deleted on the same day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237386/) does not have (status-completed) tag.

Comment: @Raff: According to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124818/135695) they've been refunded for years.  And [here's evidence the behavior hasn't changed.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261686/103167)

Comment: @BenVoigt Those are up/down votes.

Comment: @Raff: oops.  40/day seems kinda low for up/down votes, I thought the close vote cap was in that range.

Comment: Close vote cap is 50/day on SO and a few other large sites; 24 elsewhere.  To the best of my knowledge (and my experience of hitting this cap multiple times), these do not get refunded.

Comment: That is correct,  I used a few close votes so I would have noticed if they get refunded...

Comment: I think you have a great idea about allowing Club Moderators, who can close questions with 1 close vote. The rest of your post about cvpls being bad is just distracting from your good idea. So maybe I'd suggest you start a new question, with the feature-request tag just on the Club Moderators idea, so the community can decide if that's something they would want.

Comment: I'll wait and see how high this answer goes... we should work out the details of whether their powers are limited by tag (which gets in the way of cleanup of "computer won't boot" questions), whether there's a limit to the number of club votes per day, etc before making a feature request.

Comment: I am so tempted to write a cVplZ joke here :P

Comment: @rene: So, is there a "vote-to-undelete" chatroom?  (something which isn't addressed by the existing community queues, only custom flags)  Here's a candidate: user got help then erased their question denying the knowledge to future visitors: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27209414/103167

Comment: You can always create one.

Comment: @BenVoigt Although maybe not explicitly stated I'm always open for reopen and undelete requests in case I or one of my peers made a judgement that is debateable....I provided that kind of advice earlier as can be seen [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41570?m=19965370#19965370)

Comment: In case you're bothered I updated our room FAQ with how to get our help in case we  made a mistake....

Answer (score 35):

> The very phrase "close vote please", abbreviates as cvpls, is a direct request for someone to take your word for it.

No, it is not. Your question is based on a gross misconception. "Close vote please" does not entail "take my word for it" at all. "Close vote please" is an invitation to look at the question and **decide whether it should be closed.** Of course the person who makes the request thinks that the question should be closed but the person who looks is free to cast a vote *if* they agree that the question should be closed. They can also do nothing if they cannot come to a decision. Or they can challenge the person who requested a close vote if they find that the question should not be closed. It is not theoretical. I've seen such challenges multiple times myself.

If I put a close vote request for a question that says "Please give me a tool for..." I expect that people who check out the question are going to vote to close it, seeing as requests for tools are unequivocally close-worthy. However, if I put a vote request to close as because the question lacks critical information but knowing this requires acquaintance with a technology that relatively few people are familiar with, then I expect most people won't put in an additional vote because they can't determine that a vote is warranted. And I do the same when people request close-votes that hinge on knowing a technology that I don't use.

Your assumption that a request for a close vote means that the people who agree to the request are just turning off their own judgement and voting blindly is a) **insulting**, b) **not based in reality**.

Comment: Then why does the chat even say what the expected result is?  Shouldn't it be "more eyes please" or "second opinion please"?

Comment: Because cv-pls is the meme that evolved.  There wasn't any authority that came up with that term.

Comment: My assumption is based on (1) The plain english meaning of the request and (2) observed behavior.  You need to provide some evidence that these words don't mean what they appear to mean.

Comment: Aren't *you* the one that has to provide the burden of proof?  It is your question, after all.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: The plain English meaning of those words meets that burden.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Also, gnat's comment above that the queues aren't as effective as the voting rings leads me to believe that the voting rings aren't going through the decide-for-yourself process that exists in the queues.

Comment: Or, the close queue just doesn't get as much attention.  That's probably a better theory.

Comment: @Louis: You're asking me to believe that people are going to this trouble to do what the close vote queue does automatically, to merely duplicate it?

Comment: The Chat Room is real-time.  It is attractive for that reason.  Sometimes questions are so smelly that folks don't want to wait on a mod or a queue to get them shut down.

Comment: I second what Louis said in this answer. As a frequent participant of chat, I too have seen that cv-requests challenged and we go and review the question impatially. After seeing the post, we edit, vote up/down or flag the post based on our individual opinion.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Did you mean the close queue *isn't* real-time and the chatroom is?  Can we make the close queue do better?  Perhaps use LIFO order so brand new close votes get acted on very quickly?

Comment: The close queue should be LIFO anyway.  Old, abandoned questions don't need to be closed, they just need to be swept up by the Roomba.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion: So you're saying the votes pile on unless someone challenges it, and then you take the time to personally evaluate before voting?

Comment: @BenVoigt: He's saying that the folks in the Chat Room evaluate questions on their merit, and that getting the question into the chat room increases its chances of getting a rehabilitating edit.

Comment: @BenVoigt The questions that I tend to look at are those in the less popular tags. Let's take [tag:requirejs] as an example. A question there that asks for an external resource can stay with a single close vote (mine) for weeks before it gets any traction. People in the queue typically filter by the technologies they know and few are familiar with RequireJS. I could get moderator attention, say that the question should be closed,  make a case for the fact that the tag is not visited enough... or I can ask "close vote please" in chat. The latter is faster and does not require moderator time.

Comment: @Louis: Because the users in the other tags (like [tag:javascript]) don't find that in their filter?  C'mon, the PHP room is one of the biggest areas where cv-pls takes place.  If there's something about the close queue, let's figure out and fix it, not set up parallel underground systems that invite abuse.  (Note that I've never said that you personally act as a proxy... but I'm quite confident that a non-trivial number of users do)

Comment: No @Ben, votes don't pile on...chat users take a lot of effort to salvage a post, cv is the last option. The bots which offend you, do you know why those bots exist? So that all uppercase, low quality, spam and offensive posts can be salvaged by chat users. We edit to salvage, flag and cv-pls even on sites where we don't have 3k. As research for you post, please participate in the process and see how it actually works. What Louis has mentioned in this answer is the reality.

Comment: @BenVoigt I've seen many questions posted to RequireJS tag that were run-of-the-mill JavaScript issues that the OPs misidentified as RequireJS issues and remained unanswered for hours. They would have been answered in minutes if they only had the JavaScript tag. People that scan JavaScript questions specifically skip those that are also tagged with RequireJS. As for what the PHP folks do, if you find specific misbehavior address **that** rather than generalizing. I don't take a flamethrower to my garden because one corner has weeds, but that's just me.

Comment: @BenVoigt The close vote system needs a rework, sure. But the process of getting eyes on a question is *not* a "parallel underground system". We use cv-pls(z) to get rid of the worst questions fast, and without much pain. It's not an invitation to "go downvote and close this question because I hate it!", it's a "please look at this question, and close vote it if you think it should be closed".

Comment: So the bottom-line is that *cv-pls* is misnamed, and actually means "this needs editing"?  And so does *delv-pls*?  If you carefully read my idea, you'd notice that I never suggested getting rid of chat discussions about edits.

Comment: And when I see [pages of chat with more than 50% links](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/11/2013/4/25/22-24) [and even 100%](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/773/low-quality-posts-hq) that doesn't look to me like discussion of how to fix them.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion: [Whatever](http://d3u9yejw7h244g.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/on-the-internet-nobody-knows-921x1024.jpg).

Comment: @BenVoigt: The cv-pls means "I think this is worthy of closure; can some of you take a look?"  It is so named because that's the convention that happened to be adopted.  You've never seen [ill-advised naming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) before?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: There's [this whole infrastructure](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/773/low-quality-posts-hq) which isn't using the abbreviation (so you can't blame it on meme or convention) and it still *tells the reader what to do*.  I have no problem with a "Review Request" or even "This looks like spam to me, do you agree?"  But right now it is prejudiciously asking for specific votes.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Are you really going to quibble about verbiage?  Lifetimes have been wasted on this site doing just that.  "If only this word were **bolded,** nobody would ever abuse the site again."

Comment: @RobertHarvey: The suggestions you're thinking of are poor not because verbiage is unimportant, but because they suppose that new users are actually seeing the verbiage in the first place.  The verbiage I think is problematic is not directed at new users who can't find the FAQ and wouldn't read it anyway, and the change I'm challenging the "cvring is good" crowd to make if indeed they aren't proxy voting is more than just verbiage -- it's consolidating the different tags so that the reader actually has to make a decision on the appropriate action instead of "me too".

Comment: If there is no rubberstamping going on, then "review-pls" will serve just as well as the whole set of "spamflag-pls", "cv-pls", "delv-pls", etc.

Answer (score 10):

I agree that voting by proxy is not something that should be encouraged but I think you stumbled on something that is not as bad as it looks.

First and for all, the users I meet regular in the chat rooms that are involved in the [cv-pls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cv-pls) handling are all willing to invest in making SO a better place.

When cv-pls requests are posted those are either clear cases or actually harming quality. If there is a dispute that is discussed in chat, with advice how to do proper moderation in that case.

I fail to see how the extra close vote privilege for an elected user would help given the large influx of closeable questions in combination with the banning of the possiblity to moderate questions by means of chat.

If you press onwards these kind of efforts will go off-line, out-of-sight of SE users and that makes it less transparent than it is now.

I can support the extra moderator privilege. I can't support the banning of the cv-pls effort.

Comment: What need would any user have for `tag:cv-pls` via chatbot, if the site gives him a way to directly accomplish the closure?  Are you focusing on the users who couldn't garner support in an election process?  I'm assuming that the number of "club moderators" would outnumber the number of diamond mods by orders of magnitude.

Comment: How would these folks being elected change things?  Wouldn't that give them even more power than they have now?

Comment: Low traffic tags, utter crap that appears on the front page, expired votes....

Comment: @rene: That's exactly what these club moderators would be empowered to handle.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't agree with the elected part, but what do you think of an increased gold tag-badge/silver tag-badge closing system?

Comment: @hichris123 there is a related discussion at MSE: [Empowering tag-badge holders part II - let's look at silver?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240700/165773)